# react-swipe: multiple panels in view?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, swipe

I'm using the wonderful react-swipe component which is working perfectly for single-panel swiping (i.e. mobile). However, on tablet / desktop I would need to display 3 panels at once, with the center tablet 'active'.

Can I get some tips on how to adjust the styling for this component and it's children to achieve this? See attached image.[image]